# Error with curl command to server in Docker container

Tags: docker, curl, wsl-2

### Assumption

I have torchserve installed and running inside a WSL2 Docker container that makes an API for the Pytorch model.

### What I would like to achieve.

I would like to receive a list of models when I run the curl command.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8081/models
```

Expected Results

```
{
  "models": [
    {
      "modelName": "densenet161",
      "modelUrl": "densenet161.mar"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Occurring problems

The following message is returned.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirection</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Redirect</H1></BODY>
```

### What I tried

The following commands were executed from the Torchserve container

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8081/models
```

I tried with the IP address of the Docker container (172.17.0.5) but it returned an error.

```
curl 172.17.0.5:8081/models
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

When running the Docker container, I did the following port forwarding.
I ran the curl command from host to host IP address with the same result.

```
docker run -it --gpus all -v /home:/home -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 --shm-size 8GB ts_test
curl http://172.19.108.214:8081/models
```

With the -L option, an error was returned with the following results.

```
root@f0b48fd29ec1:~# curl -L http://127.0.0.1:8081/models
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

With the -v option, the following results were returned.

```
root@f0b48fd29ec1:~# curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8081/models
* Trying 10.77.8.70...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to proxy.mei.co.jp (10.77.8.70) port 8080 (#0)
> GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/models HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: BlueCoat-Security-Appliance
< Location:http://10.75.28.231
< Connection: Close
<
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirection</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Redirect</H1></BODY>
* Closing connection 0
```

What are some possible reasons why the curl command is not returning results?

Comment: have you tried `curl -L http://127.0.0.1:8081/models`?@Takayama-Shin you should login into the container.

Comment: @Dolphin
Thank you for your reply.
I logged into the container and ran the command, but it returned an error.
> root@f0b48fd29ec1:~# curl -L http://127.0.0.1:8081/models
> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: using `lsof -i:8081` to check the process listening on this port 8081 or not.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands produced the expected results.
It seems that the proxy was affecting the results.

```
root@f0b48fd29ec1:~/torchserve-sample# curl http://127.0.0.1:8081/models --noproxy "*"
{
  "models": [
    {
      "modelName": "densenet161",
      "modelUrl": "densenet161.mar"
    }
  ]
}
```